# Can we able to run npm start from Visual Studio task runner explorer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm-start, task-runner-explorer

I am setting up the Angular 4 code in Visual Studio, I can able to build successfully from Visual Studio. But if I want to start the angular code, I go to command prompt and manually type the `npm start` to run the application.

After running the `npm start`, I browse with registered port its working fine. But I don't want to use a command prompt, all I want to make it in Visual Studio task runner explorer.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `CMD-SHIFT-P` or `CTRL-SHIFT-P` and select "Tasks: Run Task", then select the "npm: start" task from the list

Comment: I don't see npm: start in the tasks list, and also I dont want to do by that way I want to happen automatically if the we run application or F5.