# How to run npm audit using the Task Runner Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-code, package.json, task-runner-explorer

I guess it is trivial, but I did not manage to figure out how to adjust my `package.json` so that I could run `npm audit` using the **[Task Runner Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TaskRunnerExplorer)** by Mad Kirstensen within **Visual Studio** (Professional 2017).

My `package.json` starts with

```
{
  "version": "1.4.6",
  "name": "myProject.UI",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "npm audit": "npm audit",
    "webpack": "webpack -w --mode='development' --colors --config webpack.config.js",
  }, ...
```

The 2nd entry in the section `scripts` works fine, the 1st one does not, since the Task Runner Explorer always adds a `cmd.exe /c npm run` as prefix to all scripts defined in `package.json`. This is what also what the error message says:

```
cmd.exe /c npm run npm audit --color=always
npm ERR! missing script: npm

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-01T01_23_45_6789Z-debug.log
```

**How do I have to modify my `package.json` to be able to start a `npm audit` using the Task Runner Explorer?**

#### Related

- [Can we able to run npm start from Visual Studio task runner explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424059/can-we-able-to-run-npm-start-from-visual-studio-task-runner-explorer)
- [No task runner configurations are found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429114/no-task-runner-configurations-are-found/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that in npm all script entries have a single string by design.

After all, `package.json` is just a json file and a such the "key" in the **key/value pairs** need to be a single valid string.

E.g. *`npm_audit`* instead of `npm audit`:

```
{
    "version": "1.4.6",
    "name":    "myProject.UI",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "npm_audit": "npm audit",
        "webpack":   "webpack -w --mode='development' --config webpack.config.js",
}, ...
```